# Part of my HTML is not displaying in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The top third of my page, including a graphic and headline, shows up just fine in Firefox and Explorer, but does not appear in Chrome when accessed from my server. It does appear in Chrome when viewing the page as a file.

The graphic is defined in the CSS file as:

```css
/** adbox **/

#adbox {
    background: #020a13 url(../images/bg-adbox.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    min-height: 433px;
    margin: -56px 0 22px;
```

And the HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Website template by freewebsitetemplates.com -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>donfiler.net - web design </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="wrapper clearfix">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="LOGO"></a>
            </div>
            <ul id="navigation">
                <li class="selected">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contents">
        <div id="adbox">
          <div class="wrapper clearfix"><p></p><p></p>
            <div class="info">
                <h1>Web Design &amp; Social Media Marketing</h1>
                <p>
                    Proven Consultant, Author | Helping Companies Translate Their Business Goals to Reality.
                </p>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="highlight">
                <h2>707-217-8457 if you want a mobile friendly web site.</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body clearfix">
            <div class="click-here">
                <h1>Impact Marketing</h1>
                <a href="https://donfiler.us/bootblog.html" class="btn1">Click Here!</a>
            </div>
            <p style="font-size:12px;">
                Proven Consultant, Author | Helping Companies Translate Their Business Goals to Reality. We design web sites with dynamic database interaction; deliver computer based training; create comprehensive marketing campaigns; specialize in hand coding HTML, CSS, PHP, Mysql and JavaScript to customize web design and user interface.
            </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <ul id="featured" class="wrapper clearfix">
            <li>
                <img src="images/THUMBNAIL_IMAGE4.jpg" alt="Img" height="204" width="180">
                <h3><a href="https://www.createspace.com/6457547?ref=1147694&utm_id=6026">Order Now</a></h3>
                <p>
                    Memories of growing up in Europe during the Cold War. The first book in a series about Don's life.  
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/THUMBNAIL_IMAGE3.jpg" alt="Img" height="204" width="180">
                <h3><a href="https://www.createspace.com/6419890">Order Now</a></h3>
                <p>
                    A catchy tune by the Beach Boys in the mid-sixties, the lyrics of "Be True to Your School" hit many highlights of high school in that era.
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/THUMBNAIL_IMAGE2.jpg" alt="Img" height="204" width="180">
                <h3><a href="https://www.createspace.com/6464083">Order Now</a></h3>
                <p>
                    College Years and Rock Band Entrepreneur. The third book in a series about Don's life.
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/THUMBNAIL_IMAGE1.jpg" alt="Img" height="204" width="180">
                <h3><a href="https://www.createspace.com/6634095?ref=1147694&utm_id=6026">Order Now</a></h3>
                <p>
                    Contributing to others is the highest form of success you can achieve and I wanted to impart what I have learned over the years working for a living.
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="body">
            <div class="wrapper clearfix">
                <div id="links">
                    <div>
                        <h4>Social</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://plus.google.com/+DonFilerRohnertPark" target="_blank">Google +</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/don.filer" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/donfiler1" target="_blank">Youtube</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Blogs</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://donfiler.blogspot.com/">Blogspot</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://impactmarketingconsultant.wordpress.com/">Marketing Blog</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="https://mobilefriendlywebdesign.wordpress.com/">Web Design Blog</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="newsletter">
                    <h4>Newsletter</h4>
                    <p>
                        Sign up for Our Newsletter
                    </p>
                    <form action="https://donfiler.us/newsletter" method="post">
                        <!--<input type="text" value="">-->
                        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up!">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <p class="footnote">
                    © Copyright © 2016 Don Filer all rights reserved.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Chrome extension AdBlock is blocking that element for me, because its ID is `adbox`. Check if you have that extension enabled, as well.

In general, try avoiding the word "ad" when naming HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

From the start, I can see a major flaw in the code- you named an element `adbox`. Most ad-blocking extensions work this way- they scan for ads, and that element will be perceived as an ad, simply because of it's name.

To quote [CapitalQ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4573410/capitalq),

> In general, try avoiding the word "ad" when naming HTML elements.

Check if you have an ad-blocking extension turned on, and if so, try the site without that extension. Also, **rename that element ASAP!**

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is spot on. I appreciate your help very much.